# Write formula to an entire range, or just loop through cells with an IF statement. Which is faster?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a macro to re-write formulas to a range in case a cell gets unintentionally modified by a user.
Would looping through each cell and fixing errors be faster then rewriting the entire range? Thoughts?

I have tried protecting sheets and certain ranges, but still occasionally have issues.

Currently using:

```
Sheet2.Range("TableSh[Produced]").Formula = "=SUMIF(TableP[Run],[@Run],TableP[Good PCS])"
```

Would this ↓ be faster?

```
For Each R In Range("TableSh[Produced]")

      If Not R.Formula = "=SUMIF(TableP[Run],[@Run],TableP[Good PCS])" Then
           R.Formula = "=SUMIF(TableP[Run],[@Run],TableP[Good PCS])"
      End If
Next
```

Comment: The not-looping solution is faster. 

Furthermore, it is easier for maintenance and more understandable. However, up to a few K cells, there would probably be no difference.

Comment: My intuition would be that this varies with how many of the cells are changed. The IF portion of the IF statement probably evaluates faster than the current method. But if the THEN statement has to be evaluated, then it's obviously slower. I'm interested to hear an experts' opinion on this though.

Comment: Most of the runtime is consumed by marshalling (Excel and VBA run in different COM apartments), while executing the particular task needs negligeble time. So, the fewer calls to Excel, the faster. Also, changing the cells formula may cause a recalculation (but I hope you already turned it off if you are interested in performance). But anyway, be a bit more empirical: run both versions 1 million times and measure the time it takes (e.g. Debug.Print Now both at the start and at the end).

Comment: @z32a7ul - I'd always thought that VBA and Excel run in the same process?  I know what you're saying is true for automation Excel from (eg) a .NET language, but I'm not sure it applies to VBA.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Same process but different COM apartments: Excel is multithreaded, while VBA is singlethreaded.

Comment: @z32a7ul - I see - thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question *"Would this ↓ be faster?"* is obviosly unnecessary if you would just run both of them and stop your time (you could easily answer that yourself).

As Vityata already said, there might only *very* rare cases where a loop is faster than *not* using a loop.
For example if the formula would be a heavy load calculation then the loop could benefit in *some* cases, especially when it only has to write very vew formulas (so we have only a vew heavy load calculations instead of a whole column).

In general I would say always try to avoid looping if there is another solution. But there is no general answer to which one is faster. Better test it on your data if you are in doubt, it highly depends on the exact situation.